# Substring after a dot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a field which holds data like this

```
Product.Company.Price.Item
```

I want to substring any string after the last dot. so it will look like this

```
Item
```

I know there is a substring.index function in MySQL. How can I implement this in SQL Server?

Comment: If it is always no more than 4 components and they happen to meet the same restrictions as identifiers then `PARSENAME('Product.Company.Price.Item',1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  reverse(substring(reverse(fieldName),1,charindex('.',reverse(fieldname))-1))
```

This will do what you want, but I wouldn't use it as part of a where expression

```
declare @x varchar(50) = 'Product.Company.Price.Item'
select  substring(@x,len(@x)-charindex('.',reverse(@x))+2,99)
```

Comment: Shouldn't need three REVERSEs. Should just need one to find out the index of the last dot relative to the end of the string. Then you can use that with RIGHT

Answer (score 1):

Hope this Query works fine for your Case:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(MAX)='Product.Company.Price.Item'

SELECT RIGHT(@VAR, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@VAR) + '.') - 1) AS VARL
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always 4 parts then you could use `parsename()` as

```
select parsename('Product.Company.Price.Item', 1)
```

or use `right()` and `charindex()` as

```
select right(str, p)
from
(
    values ('Product.Company.Price.Item'), ('Other.row')
) t(str) cross apply
(
    values (charindex('.', reverse(str))-1)
) tt(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using functions like `Reverse()`, `Left()`, and the `CHARINDEX()`.

```
DECLARE @Sentence VARCHAR(100) = 'Product.Company.Price.Item';

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@Sentence),
CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@Sentence))- 1)) AS [Last_Word]
```